# Ubuntu frozen on boot screen; boot repair fails due to X11 and gtk

Tags: boot, gtk, x11

I have a year-old HP Pavilion dv6 with Intel i7 processors and graphics card. I had Windows 7 but last week I dual booted Ubuntu. It was working fine until today.

I did the following things:

- Updated Gnome and installed Gnome tweak tool
- Uninstalled Chromium browser
- Uninstalled Google Chrome
- Moved jdk and jre folders from `~/` to `/bin` using sudo
- Moved Adobe folder from `~/` to `/bin` using sudo

Then I restarted. Ubuntu froze for half an hour on the purple boot screen. Something I did must have broken it. So, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and managed to log in through the command line. From there, I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. I also updated grub. I also installed boot-repair. However, I cannot run boot-repair, because I keep getting the following errors:

> Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed
>
> RuntimeError: Gtk couldn't be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* worK:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (you said that you can log on.)

Then choose "Ok", and select a display manager from a list. That can be lightdm, gdm, ... (if you have installed it, for example, by `sudo apt-get install gdm`)

Comment: And since you can log in, it is likely that you don't have to run boot-repair, and I don't think it is easy to launch the program from that terminal.