# Splash screen issues after force restart

Tags: plymouth

Recently a friends computer was shut down after a force restart and now it says "12.04" and a bunch of command text bleeds through the purple background. My guess is the plymouth configuration got corrupt..how do I fix this i

Comment: Hi Matthew:  If you didnt manually change any of the Plymouth configuration setting you can try  "sudo update-initramfs –u" then reboot.  See if that works first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bad reset I simply rebooted the computer and things went back to normal. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but it is solved by following the suggestion from the post [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197285/ubuntu-frozen-on-boot-screen-boot-repair-fails-due-to-x11-and-gtk/197319#197319). You may try it.
(Press control + alt + f1 to log in first.)